# How do I close a pdf file once it has printed in python?

Tags: python, pdf, printing, adobe

I am wondering how to close a pdf file once it has printed. I am using subprocess.popen to print the file but I need to physically close the acrobat application before it can go to the next file (as i believe the subprocess doesn't recognise that the process has already completed and is waiting for the user to close the application). I am running through a loop calling main when a file is found. See below.

```
def main(pdffile, printer_name):

# Set the command prompt code
cmd = '"{}" /N /T "{}" "{}"'.format(acrobat, pdffile, printer_name)
# print(cmd)

# Printing the pdf and waiting for process to finish before continuing with the rest of the script
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate('None')[0]
        
# Get File Name
filename = (os.path.basename(pdffile))
destination_folder = f'{destination_labels}' + filename
# print(destination_folder)

# Move file once printed
shutil.move(pdffile,destination_folder)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `subprocess`, I would recommend you to use the default `open()` and `close()` functions.
Here's a sample code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PDFFileReader
with open('document_path.PDF','rb') as file: #Automatically closes file when exited.
    pdf_file = PDFFileReader(file)
    first_page = pdf_file.getPage(0) # Get Page 1
    print(first_page.extractText())
```

To install PyPDF2 simply run `pip install pypdf2` in `cmd`.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to python so bare with me here but I am not exactly trying to read what is on the PDF but instead trying to print it straight to a printer. I basically have a list of courier labels that is stored in a folder. I am getting my script to print the file onto a physical printer then copy the file over and continue. I can get the first file to print but gets stuck as the subprocess doesn't think the application is terminated/completed. Hopefully you will be able to help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, the loop hole I used was `os.startfile(acrobat)`, which pre launched the adobe application. This meant that when I opened a new instance of adobe using `subprocess.popen`, once the file printed it would recognise the file as be completed and carry on with the rest of the script.